# What is MATLAB's equivalent to R's ppois(x,lambda,log.p = TRUE)?

Tags: r, matlab

I know that R's [`ppois()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.3/topics/Poisson) is equivalent to MATLAB's [`poisscdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/poisscdf.html).

However, I have a code in R that reads `ppois(x,lambda,log.p = TRUE)`.

What is the `log.p=TRUE` equivalent in MATLAB?

And similarly for the R function `dpois(x,lambda,log = TRUE)`, what is the equivalent of `log = TRUE` in MATLAB [`poisspdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/poisspdf.html)?

Do we have similar functions built into MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the R documentation correctly, all that `log.p = TRUE` does is set the output probabilities to a logarithmic scale. MATLAB's equvalent would simply be `log(poisscdf(...))`, which also sets the output to logarithmic values.

---

It has been suggested in the comments that this is a worse solution in terms of accuracy than the R version, since MATLAB supposedly doesn't use double precision values. First off: MATLAB uses double precision by default. Second: barring writing your own algorithm using [`vpa()`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), this is the easiest solution you are going to get, by a mile.

Using the timing suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652811/what-is-matlabs-equivalent-to-rs-ppoisx-lambda-log-p-true/55653124?noredirect=1#comment97996845_55653124):
R: `ppois(4,2,log.p = TRUE)` returns `-0.05408985`; MATLAB's `log(poisscdf(4,2))` returns `-0.0540898509446867`

Comment: This method (in contrast to the R function) has probably much worse precision. There is a reason why the R distribution functions can output log p-values, which are useful if p-values get very small.

Comment: @Roland be that as it may, there is simply no equivalent parameter in the MATLAB function. One could set the `'upper'` parameter to calculate more accurately on the upper end of the tail, but that's it.

Comment: Your answer should address precision. (I don't know if MATLAB uses double precision like R does.) It's a major pitfall here.

Comment: @Roland MATLAB is double precision by default, and, as I said, this is the "equivalent", since there's no build-in parameter. One could of course write their own code using `vpa()`, but that's way beyond what I'd consider 'equivalent' of a build-in function.

Comment: All I'm asking for is that you include a warning that your suggestion might have less precision than the R code ...

Comment: @Roland which I cannot truthfully do, as I don't know which of the two is more precise. I don't have any experience with R whatsoever, so for all I know it might be off the charts wrong. If someone with both programs available is willing to test precision of both methods I'd be happy to add that.

Comment: @Roland adding a warning for an hypothesis based on bad assumptions initially is definetly what I would not do. If you want to test it and evaluate it then yes, but it seems that you just do not trust matlab

Comment: What you all don't seem to get is that precision is the whole point of this parameter. People use it to avoid getting a zero p-value. This answer will return log(0) instead which doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: @Roland that's all good an well, but what you don't seem to get is that this is the only equivalent, barring writing variable precision arithmetic yourself in MATLAB, and that as I don't know R, I simply cannot comment on whether this solution would be better or worse in performance. All I did was offer the obvious alternative the OP wants. Feel free to write an answer yourself addressing the accuracy points.

Comment: @Roland that may be right, if what you are suggesting is that the mathematics under the  hood are doing something different. It'd be great if instead of suggesting it you could actually show it,either with an answer, or a comment explaining it. For now you suggested matlab doesn't uses doubles, which always has been false. (dont take this comment badly, I am genuinely suggesting it in good faith)

Comment: @Ander I'm not suggesting that. I've been told in the comments that matlab uses double precision as I know R does. I can use exactly the same approach as in this answer in R and I know that's not equivalent to OP's code. So, the answer is simply wrong and anyone relying on it will get nasty surprises. The actual answer to OP's question appears to be "no".

Comment: @Roland To add to the discussion  I run in R: `ppois(4,2,log.p = TRUE)` and returns `-0.05408985`, In matlab `log(poisscdf(4,2))` returns `-0.0540898509446867`. I am happy to test other input variables that may test your hypothesis that the log after the call may loose precision

Comment: @Ander Please refer to my previous comments on when this parameter is useful.

Comment: @Roland when I run `log(poisscdf(-1,0))` or `ppois(-1,0,log.p = TRUE)` I get `-Inf` in both R and MATLAB

Comment: Run log(ppois(1, 4999)); ppois(1, 4999, log = TRUE) in rextester.